# There's a way to add a row in SQLite Cursor in Android to use as separator?

Tags: android, sqlite, row

The problem is that I want to build a RecyclerView with sections, so for my specific case it would be good to have a "fake" row in the cursor with the category, and the other rows after it, and so on.

It's possible to do something like this?

I'm not very skilled in SQLite.

Comment: You could build a Matrix Cursor from the cursor adding the fake rows and then use the Matrix Cursor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It's possible to do something like this?

Not very easily. You could create a `CursorWrapper` that manages your fake rows, wrapping your real `Cursor`.

IMHO, it would be simpler to use an existing library for section headers (e.g., [this one](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/5132), [this one](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/4867), or others in [the Android Arsenal `RecyclerView` category](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/199)), or implement headers yourself, as I show in [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.8/RecyclerView/HeaderList).

Comment: I think this one https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/4867 will help me. I'll try. Thanks

Comment: One of the libs you provided worked very well. Thank you